# How to use development package installed by sys package manager?

Tags: apt, package-management, c++, development, header-file

I'm confused as to how to use `*-dev` packages in Ubuntu.

I want to use the `libxml2` library, in Ubuntu, for my own code development.  I installed libxml2-dev using `apt-get`, which put the header files in the `/usr/include/libxml2/libxml`.

In order to include a header file, e.g. `parse.h`, I have to use the following path `libxml2/libxml/parser.h`.   That works fine, but then I run into a cascade of problems.

`parse.h`, as written by the developer, include another header `libxml/xmlversion.h`.  Unfortunately, that path is NOT consistent with how this `-dev` package headers files are stored in Ubuntu.  That is, `xmlversion.h` needs to be called (at least by my program) as `libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h`.

Likewise, `xmlversion.h` calls a header `libxml/xmlexports.h` which also not in the default search path, creating a cascading series of "No such file" errors.

I assume that I could solve this problem by manually specifying the search path to include `/usr/local/libxml2`, but this would seem to negate the benefit of using a package manager like `apt-get`.  At the very least, I assume the package manager, when installing a `*-dev` package, will properly configure the compiler search paths

What am I missing in terms of using `*-dev` packages?  Is this normal behavior or a specific problem to `libxml2-dev`?  What does `apt` package manager expect me to do after installing an `*-dev` package?

Answer (score 2):

The development packages usually include a configuration file for `pkg-config` in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`. This program can be used (among other things) to query the needed c compiler and linker flags to use this library.

In the case of `libxml2-dev` the c compiler flags include `-I/usr/include/libxml2`:

```
$ pkg-config libxml-2.0 --cflags
-I/usr/include/libxml2
```

One way to use it would be:

```
gcc $(pkg-config libxml-2.0 --cflags --libs) main.c
```